# jquery live search

Tags: jquery

How i can i check the value of an input field continuously after it has been focused once ? (with jquery).I'm looking to make a live search and completely remove the submit button on my form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would bind the keyup and mouseup events to the input

```
$("#search").keyup(Search).mouseup(Search);

function Search(event)
{
    // keyup for keyboard entry
    // mouseup for copy-pasting with the mouse        
}
```

---

After fighting with this in jsfiddle I finally came up with this:

```
$("#search").keyup(function(e) {
    Search(e);
}).bind("paste", function(e) {
    // have to do this so the DOM can catch up on mouse right-click paste
    setTimeout(function() { Search(e); }, 100);
});
```

I wasn't aware of the `paste` event, but clearly, it is awesome

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/rLAxL/1/

Comment: Any tip for delaying the action? should i use .delay() ?

Comment: Set a bool like `searching = true` before your ajax call and check `if (!searching)` before calling it again and then set `searching = false` in the ajax complete callback. You'll also need to re-search on the latest value if it couldn't search when it wanted to

Comment: good idea :D
@everyone i used setTimeout() function for a delay but i get a error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier :/

Answer (score 2):

Bind a `keyup` event to check the content and make a request when the content is changed. To throttle the requests use a `setTimeout`.

```
$("#input").keyup(function(e){
    if (window.liveSearch) clearTimeout(window.liveSearch);
    window.liveSearch = setTimeout(function(){

        // request results here

    }, 1000); // delay time in ms
});
```

To improve performance you can save the search on an object (e.g. cache["some search"] = results) and if the same request is made, you don't have to request the server again.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#<element>').bind('keyup', function() { //do something });
```

Answer (score 0):

setInterval comes to mind.

Or you can just look at events like onKeyUp or onKeyDown or onClick, or onChange.

Comment: Not very fond of that function

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#search").on("keyup",function(){
    Search(...);
}
```

the thing is that you need to make an avatar function that call your function that do the code

or put this html as your input html:

```
<input type="text" onKeyUp="Search(this.value)"/>
```